# Using the contains method

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, contains

The objective of this program is to take the two arrays x and y and then create and array list contain numbers that occur in both x and y and then to print out this array of matching numbers. When I go to compile it gives me the error class expected on line 19 and another error saying ";" expected on the same line which I'm guessing is due to the other error. Is it just an error on that line or is it a bigger issue?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class FindCommon {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();



        int[] x = {1, 4, 3, 0, 1, 2};
        int[] y = {6, 4, 5, 0, 6, 1};


        for (int i = 0; i < x.length ; i++){

            int number = x[i];

            if (y[].(contains(x[i])){   // Line 19

                list.add(x[i]);        
            }

            System.out.println(list);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Say `if ( y.contains(x[i]) )` instead

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention I had already tried that and just checked it again now. It comes up with the Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method contains(int)
  location: variable y of type int[]

Answer (score 6):

`if (y[].(contains(x[i])){`

The above line is invalid for a various of reasons. The index for `y` array is missing. Also according to the requirement, you need to call the [`contains()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) method on the list and not the array. And there seems to be an extra pair of braces.

```
if (!list.contains(x[i])){
    list.add(x[i]); // Add to the list if it doesn't contain the value already  
}
```

You need to do the same for the elements of `y` too.

**Better Solution:** You can use a [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) instead of a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html). It'll eliminate the duplicates for you. All you need to do is just add elements to your set from both the arrays.

Comment: And there's the extra `(`. Also, this is quite possibly the point of the `Set` interface and its implementations.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Yeah mentioned that too and I was about to add the better solution to use `Set` as well! :) Thanks! :)